# Effect of App Transport Security on MobileFirst App

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

What is the effect of Apple's [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) on MobileFirst App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple blog posts have been released on this topic and more regarding iOS 9 in the MobileFirst Platform Developer Center. Please read the following:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/16/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-is-ready-for-ios-9-are-you/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/mobilefirst-platform-support-for-ios-9/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/

iOS 9-related iFixes have been released for Worklight 6.0 up to MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.2, and are available in the IBM Fix Central website for IBM customers to download.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file. Hope this helps[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obbij.png)